# Not able to select cell of tableview which is inside of UITableViewCell using xCode 12.0

Tags: uitableview, ios14, xcode12

I have tableview with images which is inside the UITableViewCell. When I click on the image then it should open full image which is working perfectly fine till now but today I just updated my xCode from 11 to 12, it stopped working and not able to select image. Now when I tap on image, it select parent tableview didSelect method instead of image of cell of inner tableview. See below image. Please let me know if anyone have solution.

[image: imagecellwithintableview]

Comment: Are you creating your cells with a Storyboard Prototype cell? Or via code with `addSubview()`?

Comment: @DonMag via the code with addSubview.

Comment: Show the code you're using to add the subviews to the cell. It sounds like you are adding them to the cell itself, when you need to be adding them to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: @DonMag wow man, it worked when adding tableview inside the contentView instead of cell itself. Thanks a lot.